# need example of PJSIP for android

Tags: android, android-studio, sip, pjsip, sip-server

I want to connect to SIP server using **PJSIP** through android, how to integrate in a android studio. I have taken example of **csipsimple** , but i am unable to connect the SIP server using **PJSIP**.

Comment: Please follow the instruction which is given by [PJSIP](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)

Comment: i am following that one, but i am getting error when i running the command ./configure-android **NDK_CC :
configure-android error: compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)** in windows

Comment: did you installed ndk before building the project?

Comment: ya..i installed ndk. can you guide, i want to use in android studio. i need connect sip server using pjsip.

Comment: you need to configure the ndk path before build pjsip. Follow this [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#BuildingPJSIP)

Comment: i am doing like this from bash command

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle"
export TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a
export APP_PLATFORM=android-28

Comment: no need to mention app platform

Comment: then i am getting this type of error, i am using windows foe building the PJSIP.  configure-android: APP_PLATFORM not specified, using android-28
configure-android: TARGET_ABI not specified, using armeabi
ls: cannot access 'C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/prebuilt/*': No such file or directory
configure-android error: compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)

Answer (score 1):

there are some misunderstanding issues on the [PJSIP android getting started](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) because they seem didn't use the newest NDK version, for the android studio, it always implements updated NDK version when u install it.
  So there are two solutions: 
            1: you download NDK version from [this website](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/), I am using version 13 which is working. then export this path instead of android studio one. 
            2: you need to specify which ABI type you need to build: there are few types of ABIs that you can build, it referred by [google's website](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am). (by add like: TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ).